# how to solve undefined reference error in C?

Tags: c, function, scanf

I'm very new to C programming and studying on K&R C Programming Language book. I'm trying to write a program converts hexadecimal numbers to decimal numbers repeatedly and want to use a function in my code. There are some problems prevent me from understanding C. I've read about them but not clearly understand.

I want to read input with length max 4, but as I understand scanf() doesn't limit length although the length of char array is 4. So I tried to eliminate non-integer characters with a for loop. Is this ok? What is the proper way of getting input from users? I don't want to use `while((cr=getchar())!=EOF)`.

When I run the program, I get an error message:"undefined reference to 'convert'". How should I define functions?

I use Code::Blocks 16.01 and MinGW.

Here is my try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>

#define LENGTH 4

int convert (char hex[]);
int result,validLength,j;
char input[LENGTH];

int main(){

    while(1){

        printf("Please enter valid hexadecimal number %d length:",LENGTH);
        scanf("%c", input);  //reading to char array

        for(j=0;j<LENGTH;j++)   // buffer
            if(input[j] > 48 && input[j] < 58)
                validLength++; 


        printf("Here is the decimal result: %d", convert(input[validLength]));

        validLength=0;

    }

    int convert(char hex[]){

        int t;

        for(t=0; t < validLength; t++)
            result= result+ hex[t]*(pow(16,(validLength-t)));

        return result;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int convert(char hex[]){ ... }` move this to outside of `main`.

Comment: `convert(input[validLength])` --> `convert(input)`

Comment: `scanf("%c", input);` --> `scanf(" %4c", input);`

Comment: `input[j] > 48` --> `input[j] >= '0'`

Comment: Should `if(input[j] > 48 && input[j] < 58)` be `if(input[j] >= '0' && input[j] <= '9')`? Your code was not accepting `'0'` and it still does not accept `'A'` to `'F'` or `'a'` to `'f'` in a hexadecimal string.

Comment: `for(t=0; t < validLength; t++)
            result= result+ hex[t]*(pow(16,(validLength-t)));` --> `for(result = t = 0; t < validLength; t++)
            result = result*16 + hex[t]-'0';`

Comment: [fixed code](http://ideone.com/gPmVrq)

Comment: @WeatherVane I've tried this:    `if(input[i] >= '0' && input[i] <= '9' || input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'f' || input[i] >= 'A' && input[i] <= 'F')` but not function as I wish. Doesnt prevent other characters.

Comment: [include A-F(a-f) ver.](http://ideone.com/Ihac6s)

Comment: @KubilayCanDEMİR I tested that and it does work, maybe your implementation was faulty. But as BLUEPIXY uses in his code `isxdigit` is there in `ctype.h` for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1] You cant have nested function. Move it out of the body.

2] Here

```
printf("Here is the decimal result: %d", convert(input[validLength]));
```

You are passing an `char`, but `convert` function expect's `char*`. Correct:

```
printf("Here is the decimal result: %d", convert(input));
```

3] `%c` specifier is for character's, use `%s` and better with how many chars to read `%4s`. Dont forget to check return value e.g.

```
if(scanf("%4s", input) != 1)
{
    // Fail
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is invalid:

```
scanf("%c", input);
```

The `%c` format specifier will only read a single character.  If you want to read a string, you need to use `%s`.  Also, you should put a length modifier on this field to specify the maximum number of characters to read:

```
scanf("%4s", input);
```

You'll need to make `input` one element larger to have room for the terminating null byte.

Also, you attempted to define your `convert` function inside of your `main` function.  Nested functions are not supported in standard C.

You need to move the definition of `convert` outside of `main`:

```
int convert (char hex[]);
int result,validLength,j;
char input[LENGTH+1];

int convert(char hex[]){

    int t;

    for(t=0; t < validLength; t++)
        result= result+ hex[t]*(pow(16,(validLength-t)));

    return result;

}

int main(){

    while(1){

        printf("Please enter valid hexadecimal number %d length:",LENGTH);
        scanf("%4s", input);  //reading to char array

        // initialize validLength, otherwise you increment an uninitialized value
        validLength = 0;
        for(j=0;j<LENGTH;j++)   // buffer
            if(input[j] > 48 && input[j] < 58)
                validLength++; 

        // null terminate after the invalid characters
        input[validLength] = 0;

        printf("Here is the decimal result: %d", convert(input));

        validLength=0;

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `convert` inside of main function - move it outside and it fix the error.

Also, in order to store `scanf` result of lenght 4 your `input` should be 5, since so called C-string is terminated with NULL. (E.g. when you type A0CD, values in input will be `{'A', '0', 'C', 'D', 0}`